# Help with Japanese sentence order

Tags: grammar, sentence

So, I recently decided to take a try at Japanese again. As such I decided to jump right in to using the vocabulary I know in sentences to see how far I could get. The following is what I came up with, I'll put the meaning I'm attempting to convey in English beside the Japanese.

> これは僕の物語り！！！(This is my story [tale]!)
>   けど、これはその男の物語りも。 (But, this is that man's story as well.)
>   はい、そうです。 (Yes, that is true.)
>   しかし、物語じゃない。(But, this is not a story.)
>   これは君の未来！ (This is your future!)
>   何？嘘ですね？(What? You're lying, right?)
>   嘘じゃない。 (I'm not lying.)
>   そう。。。わかりました。でも、僕？なんで！？(Okay...I understand. But, me? Why me?)

What I'm most concerned with is the sentence order and if it is understandable. Not so much with if I could have left out a pronoun or something along those lines. I know this is a lot to ask but thank you very much to anyone who is willing to help!

Comment: `sentence order` -- "word order" (語順) じゃなく？

Comment: @Chocolate sentence order can mean "the order of the sentence" cant it? My english is falling me... but anyways, you both are meaning the same thing, I guess.